# Laptop Warranty - Lenovo ideapad 100

Tags: lenovo-laptop, warranty

Two weeks back I bought a new laptop 100. When i started working, i noticed in solution center as "your warranty expires in 10 days".  I checked with the dealer, he says not to worry on that and i'm covered with one year warranty.

What do I do?

Comment: Sounds like the laptop wasn't actually new.

Answer (score 2):

For your peace of mind, I would suggest calling Lenovo customer support and giving the serial number to them to confirm, they should be able to tell you how long you have under their warranty.

[Lenovo Support](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/)

Try clicking "Contact Us" and it will ask you to check your serial/product number, perhaps that will provide some more help also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following link: [Lenovo Warranty Lookup](http://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/warrantylookup)

That should give you an idea as to the actual expiry date.